# Wait a result from a API using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, q

I'm quite new to Node.js. I would like to call an API and wait the result before to do something.

```
// endpoint
function getListMarket() {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  deferred.resolve(Q().then(getMarkets)
  .then(calculIndicators));
  return deferred.promise;
}

// Get a list
function getMarkets() {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  bittrex.getmarketsummaries(function (data, err) {
    if (err) deferred.reject(err.name + ': ' + err.message);
    if (data) {
      var listMarkets = [];
      for (var i in data.result) {
         listMarkets.push(data.result[i]);
      }

      deferred.resolve(listMarkets);
    }
  });

  return deferred.promise;
}

// Update a Coin
function calculIndicators(coinList) {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  var promises = [];
  coinList.forEach(function (coin) {
    promises.push(getCandles(coin).then(getIndicators(coin)));
  });

  Q.allSettled(promises).then(function (results) {
    console.log('3 ---------------------------------------------');
    var listMarkets = [];
    results.forEach(function (r) {
       console.log("result ok" + r.value.name);
    });

    deferred.resolve(listMarkets);
  });

  return deferred.promise;
}

// Get a information needed to update the coin
function getCandles(coin) {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  bittrex.getcandles({
    marketName: coin.MarketName,
    tickInterval: 'hour', // intervals are keywords (oneMin, fiveMin, hour, thirtyMin, Day)
  }, function (data, err) {
        if (err) {
          deferred.reject(err.name + ': ' + err.message);
        }

        if (data) {
          console.log('1 : data');
          coin.Test= 10;
          deferred.resolve(coin);
        }
      });

  return deferred.promise;
}

// Update the coin with the information from getCandles
function getIndicators(coin) {
  console.log('2 : ' + coin.Test);
}
```

In this case, when I call my function getListMarket, the output is :

```
2 : undefined
2 : undefined
2 : undefined
...
1 : data
1 : data
1 : data
...
3 ---------------------------------------------
```

Can you explain me why the log "2" is called before the 1 in this case ?
I think the api in getCandles is an Asynchronous Calls but I don't know why.
I need the result of this api in the function getIndicators.

Comment: you are calling getIndicators way too early.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear everything you're trying to do here, but you need to do a whole bunch of things better:

1. Avoid the deferred anti-pattern (wrapping a promise in another manually created promise).
2. Make sure you're always returning the resolved value from within a `.then()` handler.
3. Avoid calling your function too early when passing to `.then()`.  It should be `.then(fn)`, not `.then(fn())`.
4. Fill in some missing code that sets the value of `listMarkets`.

Here's the code with a bunch of things fixed (the code still seems unfinised in several areas as it's not clear what you're trying to do in some places):

```
// endpoint
function getListMarket() {
  return getMarkets().then(calculIndicators);
}

// Get a list
function getMarkets() {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  bittrex.getmarketsummaries(function (data, err) {
    if (err) {
        deferred.reject(err.name + ': ' + err.message);
    } else {
      var listMarkets = [];
      for (var i in data.result) {
         listMarkets.push(data.result[i]);
      }
      deferred.resolve(listMarkets);
    }
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}

// Update a Coin
function calculIndicators(coinList) {
  var promises = [];
  coinList.forEach(function (coin) {
    promises.push(getCandles(coin).then(getIndicators));
  });

  return Q.allSettled(promises).then(function (results) {
    console.log('3 ---------------------------------------------');
    var listMarkets = [];
    results.forEach(function (r) {
       console.log("result ok" + r.value.name);
    });

    // Fixme: you need ro fill in listMarkets here
    return listMarkets;
  });
}

// Get a information needed to update the coin
function getCandles(coin) {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  bittrex.getcandles({
    marketName: coin.MarketName,
    tickInterval: 'hour', // intervals are keywords (oneMin, fiveMin, hour, thirtyMin, Day)
  }, function (data, err) {
        if (err) {
          deferred.reject(err.name + ': ' + err.message);
        } else {
          console.log('1 : data');
          coin.Test= 10;
          deferred.resolve(coin);
        }
      });

  return deferred.promise;
}

// Update the coin with the information from getCandles
function getIndicators(coin) {
  console.log('2 : ' + coin.Test);
  return coin;
}
```